# Allow only one radio button to be selected from multiple groups of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a number of **account** items.

I am displaying these in a list doing something like

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">
```

and for every such item i display three radio buttons in a group, holding values like

- admin
- user
- moderator

Right now a user can select a value for each group of radio buttons, but what I want to do is have only one admin.

So if an admin value is selected the I should block all other admin radio buttons.

How can this be done?

Comment: Sorry your title says checkboxes and your question has radio buttons?

Comment: @WayneEllery sorry about that, fixed it.

Comment: Is it a group of checkboxes or radio buttons because you question says radio buttons and the little still says checkboxes

Comment: No no its radio boxes, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Define `only one admin`. That can be interpreted several ways

Comment: Imagine a list of five groups of radio boxes. Every group has those three values. But in all these five groups there can be only one admin. So if I select in some group the value for admin, then this value should be disabled in all the other frour groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a ng-change method that stores the admin item in a scope property to keep track of which item has admin selected:

```
$scope.radioChanged = function (item) {
  if (item.selectedValue == "admin") {
    $scope.admin = item;
  }
  else if (item == $scope.admin) {
    $scope.admin = undefined;
  }
};
```

Then use ng-disabled on the admin radio button that will disable the radio button if an admin has been selected and the admin is not the current item.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <label><input type="radio" name="{{item.id}}" value="admin" ng-model="item.selectedValue" ng-change="radioChanged(item)" ng-disabled="admin && item != admin"/>admin</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="{{item.id}}" value="user" ng-model="item.selectedValue" ng-change="radioChanged(item)"/>user</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="{{item.id}}" value="moderator" ng-model="item.selectedValue" ng-change="radioChanged(item)"/>moderator</label>
</div>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cev7PC6aBoEykWdVyg9r?p=preview)

Comment: This can more easily be used with repeat, thus I believe most people coming here will be interested for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a variable, maybe `adminExists`, that is set to `true` when you select 'Admin' on any of the radio buttons. You could then have all the "Admin" radio buttons become disabled `if(adminExists && !isSelected)`, where `isSelected` is true if that radio button is the admin button that was selected.

Comment: I did try to do it like this, but there is a problem though. The radio buttons will never update and become disabled. I dont know why. Can You provide a fiddle of this?

Comment: They would only become disabled if those variable where set before the page loaded, not during the time that the user might decide to change a value.

Comment: @dearn44 you should provide the demo and let others modify it. Starting from scratch means asking others to do all the initial setup

Comment: @dearn44 but if you try to disable them at the time the event (click) triggers, won't they update?

Comment: You are correct I should have provided something for you to go by, Ill do a quick demo wait.

Comment: Here's a basic proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnBarton27/qfyzL8ub/5/

There's no ng-repeat, but it shows essentially what you could do.

Comment: Meanwhile I am failing with the basics, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doaqpM
The app itself is quite big so I tried to only add the radiobuttons part, for some reason they do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

The code below checks the value of the selected radio button against the value of other radio buttons to see if they match up (in this case if the value is "admin"). It then deselects all the radio input elements with that value and then checks the element that was initially clicked or selected to set it to active. You can change the function to use a data attribute instead of the value if you'd prefer as well.

```js
$(".group input[type=radio]").bind("click change keydown focus", function () {
    var el = $(this);
    var val = el.val();
    if (el.prop("checked", true) && val == "admin") {
        $(".group input[type=radio]").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "admin") $(this).prop("checked", false);
        });
        el.prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

```css
.choice {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="group[0][]" value="admin" />
            <label>Admin</label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="group[0][]" value="user" />
            <label>User</label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="group[0][]" value="moderator" />
            <label>Moderator</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="group[1][]" value="admin" />
            <label>Admin</label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="group[1][]" value="user" />
            <label>User</label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
            <input type="radio" name="group[1][]" value="moderator" />
            <label>Moderator</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is there something wrong with it? I upvoted it because of the different approach even though I chose Johns answer.

Comment: @downvoter, I'd like to know why this was downvoted as well. I believe this answer does what the OP is asking other than disabling the input, I used an approach that would still allow someone to change their mind in terms of selecting to be admin of one group over another

Comment: The question is an angular question and you answered it with a jQuery solution.