# Radiobutton wont react to ng-change directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

This question is linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857877/allow-only-one-radio-button-to-be-selected-from-multiple-groups-of-checkboxes/31858657#31858657).

While trying to experiment with the suggestions on these answers, I ran into some trouble. What I tried to do is do the same thing but using the official angular material example as can be seen below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.10.0/angular-material.css'>
</head>

<body ng-app="radioDemo1" layout="row">
<div>
  <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="c in radioData">    
        <md-radio-group class="choice" ng-required="true" ng-change="radioChanged(account)" ng-model="c.selectedValue" >
          <md-radio-button value="Apple" class="md-primary" >Apple</md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button value="Banana" > Banana </md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button value="Mango" >Mango</md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>
      <div>   
      </form>
    </div>

    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.10.0/angular-material.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js'></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        'use strict';
        angular
      .module('radioDemo1', ['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = {
          group1 : '1',
          group2 : '2',
          group3 : '3'
        };

        $scope.radioData = [
          { label: '1', value: 1 },
          { label: '2', value: 2 },
          { label: '3', value: '3', isDisabled: true },
          { label: '4', value: '4' }
        ];
        $scope.radioChanged = function (item) {
            console.log(item);
            if (item.selectedValue == "Apple") {
              $scope.admin = item;
            }
            else if (item == $scope.admin) {
              $scope.admin = undefined;
            }
          };
      })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The thing with this code is that my function for checking the value of the selected radio button never gets called.

Why is that, and how can I fix this, so the check does get performed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `ng-model` and `ng-change` are only allowed inside an `md-radio-group` element.

Also as **overburn** said you have to also be careful when using md-model.

Thus the solution to this issue would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.10.0/angular-material.css'>
</head>

<body ng-app="radioDemo1" layout="row">
<div>
  <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="c in radioData">    
        <md-radio-group class="choice" ng-required="true" ng-change="radioChanged(c)" ng-model="c.selectedValue" >
          <md-radio-button value="Apple" class="md-primary" ng-disabled="admin && item != admin">Apple</md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button value="Banana" > Banana </md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button value="Mango" >Mango</md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>
      <div>   
      </form>
    </div>

    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.10.0/angular-material.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js'></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        'use strict';
        angular
      .module('radioDemo1', ['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = {
          group1 : '1',
          group2 : '2',
          group3 : '3'
        };

        $scope.radioData = [
          { label: '1', value: 1 },
          { label: '2', value: 2 },
          { label: '3', value: '3', isDisabled: true },
          { label: '4', value: '4' }
        ];
        $scope.radioChanged = function (item) {
            console.log(item);
            if (item.selectedValue == "Apple") {
              $scope.admin = item;
            }
            else if (item == $scope.admin) {
              $scope.admin = undefined;
            }
          };
      })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have the same model on all the radio buttons.

Radio buttons are basically an array of values, so if you put different models on them, they won't actually change because they only have one possible value each.

Try:

```
<md-radio-group class="choice">
          <md-radio-button ng-model="data.group_unique" value="Apple" class="md-primary" ng-change="radioChanged(account)">Apple</md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button ng-model="data.group_unique" value="Banana" ng-change="radioChanged(account)"> Banana </md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button ng-model="data.group_unique" value="Mango" ng-change="radioChanged(account)">Mango</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

Comment: Originally I tried having my model on the radio-group `<md-radio-group ng-model="c.group1">` but I got Controller `'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!`. Also even if I use the same model still the function wont get called.

Comment: you need to put the model on each of the buttons, not on the radio group

Comment: Please do give a look at [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.radioButton) though. They have the model on the group, thats why I tried it. In any case this does not seem to be connected with my issue. The function will not get called even with your changes.

Comment: Weird, this seems to work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOXraV; That ng-repeat might be the source of your issues tho.

Comment: The thing is that I need the repeat because I dont know how many objects there might be. Also at this [this](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1963) they are suggesting that model, and change should be on radio-group. But of curse when I tried it I got the error I told you about.